# Broken emacs trying to tangle multiple org files into a config.el file

Tags: init-file, org-babel

Help! I've broken my emacs configuration. I was trying to sort out my messy config.el file by dividing it into multiple .org files.

My init.el file now looks like this

```
(require 'org)
(org-babel-load-file
 (expand-file-name "config.org"
                   (expand-file-name "/Users/ljs46/.emacs.d")))
```

My config.org contains the following.

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:emacs-lisp :tangle config.el

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
#+INCLUDE: personal-info.org
#+INCLUDE: general-settings.org
#+INCLUDE: keybindings.org
#+INCLUDE: package-management.org
#+INCLUDE: functionality.org
#+INCLUDE: ess.org
#+INCLUDE: pdf.org
#+INCLUDE: org.org
#+INCLUDE: spelling.org
#+INCLUDE: AUCTeX.org
#+end_src
```

Just to give an example of one of my org files, here is my (very basic) ess.org

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:emacs-lisp :tangle yes
* ESS Configuration
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: ess-configuration
  :END:
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
 ;; Set default R version, (i.e. the one launched by typing M-x R <RET>)
  (setq inferior-R-program-name "/usr/local/bin/R")

  ;; Allow hash to be entered  
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-3") '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "#")))
  #+END_SRC
```

I am using MaOS 12.0.1 and emacs 29.1 universal binary.

If anyone can help me solve this, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Solve what? You say nothing about what you mean by "broken".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not have an `emacs-lisp` source block surrounding your includes: they are not `emacs-lisp` code. But the main problem is that you expect the `#INCLUDE:`s to be expanded on tangling: they are not, they are only expanded on [export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html).
Most "literate" `config.org` files that I've seen are huge *single* files: they don't use `#+INCLUDE:` at all (e.g. https://www.lucacambiaghi.com/vanilla-emacs/readme.org was the first random hit I looked at).

You *can* use `#+INCLUDE:` but not in the file that `org-babel-load-file` will process (first tangle and then load). If your `config.org` contains `#INCLUDE:` lines, you will need to *expand* those lines (i.e. replace them with the *contents* of the included file). Since that expansion only happens during export, you will need to *export* your org file to a *different* file.

Org mode provides an export backend to produce Org mode files: all the transformations (`#+INCLUDE:` processing, `MACRO:`  processing, etc.) will be done, but the final transcoding will be more or less trivial: the file contents are almost literal copies of the contents of the included files.

So try it: get rid of the emacs-lisp source block markers, and export the `config.org` file using `C-c C-e O o`, i.e. to an Org mode file. The resulting file will be called `config.org.org` to distinguish it from the original, but you should probably rename it to something like `post-config.org` (or name your original file `preconfig.org` and then rename the export output file (which would be `preconfig.org.org`) to `config.org`. I'll assume you have done the latter for definiteness.

So you started with a `preconfig.org` (which contains `#+INCLUDE:`s) and exported it to `preconfig.org.org` with `C-c C-e O o` and then renamed that to `config.org`. This file now does not contain any `#+INCLUDE:` lines: they have been replaced by the contents of the various files.

You can now give *that* `config.org` file to `org-babel-load-file`: it will tangle it to produce a `config.el` and then it will load the `config.el` file. There are many possibilities of more errors, but if you understand the basic flow, you should be able to debug them: look at the preprocessed `config.org` to familiarize yourself with what it looks like, then look at the tangled `config.el` (tangle it by hand with `C-c C-v C-t` first and look at it before going further; *if* it looks reasonable, try to load it manually using `M-x load-file`; *if* that works, *then* try your three-line `init.el` file). If something is broken, find out where in the pipeline the breakage occurred and carry it back all the way to your `preconfig.org` or (more likely) the included file that caused the breakage; fix it and regenerate the `config.org` file. Then go through the whole sequence, producing the various files by hand and examining them carefully.

Comment: Thanks. That solves my problem, and clears up some confusion my part. I am going to try and solve it a different way, which is to write an lisp function to load each of the subordinate files. That way I can also make them load conditionally, for example, ess configuration loads only when I visit a .R file, for example.

Comment: SInce it solves your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.