# Using .org to create init.el

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I've recently learnt  about using a .org file to create init.el and would like to move to this construct to better document my setup. One thing I have thought about is trying to compartmentalise this by having numerous .org files, one for each property, ie. themes package management etc. but can't figure out how to go about that. Can I embed .org docs within a .org doc? In effect the main .org doc would be an index to each function I wanted to include in the final init.el.

Comment: For one possible way, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79808/broken-emacs-trying-to-tangle-multiple-org-files-into-a-config-el-file/79810#79810 - but it complicates the production of the `init.el` file, making it even more likely that something in the chain will break. It is simpler to start with a single Org mode file (you can e.g. organize it by having a single section for each "atomic" component of your init file) - there are many questions that address that setup on this site (and on the web). Search for `[org] tangle init.el` on this site as a start.